# Why use while over if in single wordpress posts?

Tags: theme-development, themes, single, core

Why is `while()` used instead of say `if()` here:

```
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?>

        <?php _s_post_nav(); ?>

        <?php
            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
            if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) :
                comments_template();
            endif;
        ?>

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

So I've seen this since forever and I've used it too because it's what Wordpress uses by default. However today I'm feeling a bit more curious than usual - why is while used instead of if ? Am I expecting to receive more than a single post in single post view ?

https://github.com/Automattic/_s/blob/master/page.php#L18
https://github.com/Automattic/_s/blob/master/single.php#L13

Comment: I am not sure if there is any need for using it. `have_posts()` is always true for `single` template files. I don't use `if` or `while` on these template files. Just `the_post()` before showing contents and it works just fine for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [the WordPress Codex for `have_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/have_posts) points out:

> As a side effect, have_posts starts, steps through, or resets The Loop. At the end of the loop, have_posts returns 0 after calling rewind_posts.

Looking at the source as it stands today: along with calling `rewind_posts()` it also fires the `loop_end` action (which plugins may rely upon) as well as set a flag so `in_the_loop()` correctly returns false afterwards.

So calling `have_posts()` on each iteration does more than just return a Boolean.  I wouldn't lean too much on the specifics of the source because that's a moving object. It's enough to understand that there are other housekeeping tasks performed when you call `have_posts()` until it returns false and you're less likely to introduce subtle interoperability issues if you use it that way even when there is only a single post involved.

Comment: Great answer! However, it does one more important thing, and I would suggest you to edit your answer so it's complete. It also sets the `in_the_loop` property to false, basically saying that the loop has been completing and causing the `in_the_loop()` method of `$wp_query` and therefore the global `in_the_loop()` function (if it's the global query) to return false.

Comment: Good points; also edited for the sake of hopefully being a more future-proof answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must be use in single post or detail post because you does not get post meta field.
For example you have one custom post type like "Product" in admin side
and than you add just custom fields to product(Extra filed such as price,number etc).
In short you use while loop than you can get extra field like as get post meta otherwise you can not get extra field
Is possible when you are using while loop in single.php